# Notifying ViewController from model(networkClient) in swift

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, nsnotificationcenter, uiapplicationdelegate

**I have some complex networking in my app**( I don't use any third party dependencies, because of project requirements). For instance, I send three network requests in parallel after first two requests provide results. All my networking is done in separate models, known as networkClients(following MVC-S pattern) and are **called directly from repository**, not from ViewControllers. **However, I need the last request to notify my viewController after I get response from network.** How should I do that? I don't think notification center would be right solution because it can cause memory leaks and I have not found correct approach to complex problem like this. Please provide some prominent solutions. It should conform to good design pattern like MVVM or MVC and should not be some workaround or hack. Maybe delegates would work? *I know that rxSwift would solve my issue, because I could start observing for results after initializing viewController and after data would be updated from repository my viewController would also be notified...*

Comment: Can you clarify "the last request"?  Do you mean the last to complete?

Comment: I think notification center is perfect for such scenario. patterns are used to solve problem, not cause problem.

Comment: [Here are two ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39309450/1971013).

Comment: @danh yes, the last request completes and it gets some data(also this request is called multiple times until certain condition is satisfied, then API pinning stops). But results should be send to viewController every time.

Comment: @meaning-matters I use dispatchGroup but for another purpose. For instance: it helps me to determine when should I send my final request. It works really well. However, how should I notify my ViewController after DispatchGroup fires notify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right design doesn't have VCs observing the network clients directly.  Those network operations should be assembling parts of a **model**, which is what the VC really cares about. Have the VC observe that singular model.

It can do this observing using one of the well known patterns for loosely coupled communication between objects.  The OP correctly mentions delegates. Notification center and KVO are others. There's plenty of discussion on SO about which to use and how to implement. (I'd go with `NSNotificationCenter` as an easy and rational start).

So the order of operation is like this:

1. allocate the model
2. launch the network requests and setup those request completions (completion blocks, probably) to update that model with their responses.  (the model can launch the requests, which is a reasonable practice).
3. create the view controller(s) that setup model observation when they initialize (probably, in `viewWillAppear` or later)

What about the fact that >1 requests are in flight simultaneously?  A commenter above points out correctly that GCD offers a way to group those async operations into a single one. But you can do this yourself straight-forwardly: the model decides when it's completely built. The completion code for each request will change some condition in the model to the "ready" state. Each request completion can check to see whether *all* of the ready conditions are met, and only then post a "ready" notification for observers to see.

Another niggling issue: what if those requests all run very, very fast? Maybe there's some cached response that's ready early, making the model "ready" before the VC has had a chance to setup observation?  Handle this straight-forwardly in the VC: before observing the model, check to see if it's ready already and run the same update code that runs on the notification.

Comment: This is really very clear explanation. Really appreciate your two lasts paragraphs.. Maybe I have not explained myself perfectly, but this is what I meant about network requests coming from model. 
Model(it is called repository) starts required network request after another request handles completion block. This model (repository) uses another model (network client) with all code needed for creating requests and executes it.

After that (network client) provides completion block to repository and my repository can launch notification, yes? :) That notification should be observed in VC, yes?

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov - I think I understand you, and yes.  It sounds like the repository, once it's built, contains everything that the VC needs know about.  So its reasonable to call that your VC's model. Have that repository check the ready condition and have it notify the world that it is ready.  I probably wouldn't apply the term "model" to the network client.

Comment: yes, but one more detailed to be clear: this repository is singleton, because it has some information, which another VC's also need and logic is shared. Like first VC does 1/3 of a job, second VC another 1/3 and third does final part. And all data which is relevant for whole app functionality is stored in repository. I found that in this case singleton pattern is decent idea. Yes, network client might be called a helper

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov, I agree.

Comment: Really thank you... this information is priceless! You should write some blog or maybe Medium post! 10/10 quality!